# Trouble authorizing Everpad on Lubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, evernote

Due to heating issues I switched to a lighter version of Ubuntu i.e Lubuntu 12.10 from Ubuntu 12.04 . I was using Everpad in Ubuntu 12.04 without problems, but can't get it going on Lubuntu 12.10.

The issue is that after I authorize I am thrown back to Everpad Settings/Management console and instead of `de-authorize` I see `authorize` in the `Authorization` section of software. I've tried to re-install the s/w and tried deleting the `.everpad` directory in my home directory but it doesn't help.

I installed the software following the instructions in [Everpad 2.0 released with new features](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/everpad-20-released-new-features)

Comment: According to [the link](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/everpad-20-released-new-features) you provided, Everpad seems very customized for Unity. You could try asking at the ppa's [Launchpad page](https://answers.launchpad.net/~nvbn-rm) or in the [Lubuntu mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/lubuntu-users).

Comment: According to the blog link, the ppa is `ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa`. But [this Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~nvbn-rm/+archive/everpad-usc) also has `ppa:nvbn-rm/everpad-usc`.

Comment: @vasa1, I was able to find a work-around for this persistent issue by installing gnome-shell but everytime I need to make changes to software or even sync I have to go choose gnome-de and make the changes. One can find details/screenshot of the issue on `https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/210`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar issue by killing the everpad-provider process. Try the following command, then see if it works again:

```
killall everpad-provider
```